# Need to install pandas library directly from a python file on MacOS

Tags: python, pandas, macos, operating-system

I am required  to use a fresh Mac OS with no libraries unless I can find a way to download pandas using a .py file on the fresh VM. How would I do this on MacOS?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to have the entire `.tar.gz` download in order to install the package, not just a single `.py` file. As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36014572/3923163) as well, once you have the `.tar.gz`, you can unpack it, navigate to the directory, and execute the `setup.py` file:

```
python setup.py install
```

You can get the latest version of pandas [here](https://pypi.org/project/pandas/#files).

### Update after comment/update

Check out using [subprocess](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47059526/3923163) to issue commands.

```
import subprocess
import sys

version = 0.24.2
package = 'pandas'

subprocess.call(['sudo', sys.executable, '-m', 'pip', 'install', '{}=={}'.format(package, version)])
```

Comment: I meant something like this (for windows):     'import os
cmd = 'sudo pip install pandas'
os.system(cmd)'

Answer (score 0):

If you have already installed pip with your python setup, you can download the wheel file of pandas library and install it using pip.

More about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27885397/how-do-i-install-a-python-package-with-a-whl-file?rq=1).